# DB2 SQL query to SUM the column and Subtract column

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

I have `TRAN_AM` (Transaction amount) and `DB_CRD_ID`(Debit Credit ind). I have to SUM the TRAN_AM based on the credit debit indicator in a single query.

Input:

```
Acct     TRAN_AM     DB_CRD_ID
AAAAAA    10             D 
AAAAAA    10             C
AAAAAA    10             D
```

My output should be 10, D. Also have to manage negative if Credit is higher.

This query will be used as subquery, As I have to compare this amount with the another table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SUM(TRAN_AM * 
        case DB_CRD_ID 
            when 'D' THEN 1
            when 'C' THEN -1
        END
       ) 
 from TABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried below and it worked.
`
SELECT  sum(CASE WHEN B.DB_CRD_ID = 'C' then B.TRAN_AM
                  WHEN B.DB_CRD_ID = 'D' then -B.TRAN_AM
                   END) AS NETAMOUNT
                   FROM TABLE
`